# How do I set an exception for windows 10 firewall?

Tags: networking, windows-10, google-chrome, firewall

I've blocked my inbound and outbound connections of my PC in firewall and set some rules for some programs such as "**Chrome**" so they can access internet .
But sometimes I have a problem with some programs ( such as "**Gramblr**" or "**Lantern**" ) that wanted to access a localhost address ( like this => http://localhost:7470/?1 ) even when I put the EXE file in my firewall rules to allowing them access internet !
Those programs work fine without firewall but I need to have firewall to block all connections except those I needed .
Please help me solve this problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to block localhost connections with Windows 7/2008R2 firewall](http://superuser.com/questions/401900/how-to-block-localhost-connections-with-windows-7-2008r2-firewall)

Comment: If you're not talking about trying to allow/block access to Localhost, then please better explain your problem, as-is it's a little hard to figure out exactly what's going on.